# MySQL different approaches to store coordinates

Tags: mysql, coordinates, gis, geospatial

I have some SQL for MySQL that inserts both a point and a polygon into a database. This code works. However I’m seeing multiple ways to do this online and it’s not clear what is the right approach.

This is my current way:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df0e51/1

```
CREATE TABLE `Grid` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `point` POINT DEFAULT NULL,
  `polygon` polygon DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO `Grid`(point, polygon) 
VALUES(POINTFROMTEXT('POINT(49.227239 17.564932)'),POLYGONFROMTEXT('POLYGON((0 5, 2 5, 2 7, 0 7, 0 5))'));
```

However Ive also seen tutorials using the geometry type with insert statements containing ST_GeomFromText to achieve exactly the same thing.

My question is, is there a right way to do this, or at least, how do I know when to use one or the other?

Comment: I think you will find the answer is "Horses for Courses" It really depends what you have as input

Comment: Maybe `MySQL` [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/populating-spatial-columns.html) will help

Comment: If we used the input data above in the example would that help narrow it down?

Comment: Thank you Ergest. If anything that adds more options such as ST_PointFromText but I think that is just a variation on ST_geomfromtext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons to prefer `ST_GeomFromText`:

- It is more general than the MySQL `POINTFROM/POLYGONFROM` functions because it looks at the text definition and determines which kind of geometry it is, making your code potentially cleaner.
- Functions with prefix `ST_` conform to the behavior defined by Open Geospatial Consortium for geospatial SQL, and so are portable across different database types.  The MySQL aliases without `ST_` will probably just work on MySQL.